# calculating gravitational constant using Semi-major axis and orbit period

Tags: proof-explanation

I have been having trouble calculating the gravitational constant (*G*) using Kepler's third law.
given **Mercury** has a semi-major axis of 0.39 AU, and an orbital period of 0.24 years, and that the **sun** has a mass of $1.989 * 10^{30} kg$, I tried to calculate *G* using [image: Wikipedia-g-formula] where M is the mass of the sun.

I did $39.478 *(0.24^{-2} * 0.39^3) * (1.989*10^{30})^{-1}*$ which equals to $2.04405086E-29$, but that is not the value of *G* which is supposed to be $6.6743*10^{-11} m^3 * kg ^{-1} * s^{-2}$. what am I doing wrong here to be so far off?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Are all your units correct?